# SitePrism gem- how to set_url dynamically based on the environment?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, site-prism

I'm converting the in-browser tests for an app to use the SitePrism gem.  In the gem readme, I see the following:

```
A page usually has a URL. If you want to be able to navigate to a page, you'll need to set its URL. Here's how:

    class Home < SitePrism::Page
      set_url "http://www.google.com"
    end

If you've set Capybara's app_host then you can set the URL as follows:

    class Home < SitePrism::Page
      set_url "/home.htm"
    end
```

I anticipate needing to run these tests in multiple environments (i.e. locally, and on a staging server).  I'm wondering how I would call Capybara's app_host method dynamically.  Would I add something like this to my spec_helper file?

```
Capybara.app_host = ENV[URL]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in `rails_helper`, after loading the environment, eg:

```
case Rails.env
when "test"
  # use default
when "staging"
  Capybara.app_host = "http://www.google.com"
else
  raise "could not set app_host for environment: #{Rails.env}"
end
```